# Bootstrap slider in ASP.NET MVC from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, slider, slideshow

I tried to make Bootstrap carousel slider for news from SQL Server database

I want the slider to look like this: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

But the role said

> The .active class needs to be added to one of the slides. Otherwise, the carousel will not be visible.

but I did not know how to use .active class to one of my news because it is foreach loop.

All of my news has been under each other also, the left and right controls not working

[Here is a screenshot of news slider result now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDs6h.jpg)

The code now:

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View(db.News.ToList());
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.News>
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<!--Start slide code-->
<div class="container imgs">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active"> //My mistake is here, how to make first news of class active?
                    <div class="item ">
                        @{ string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.newImg);
                            string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                            <img src="@imageSrc" />
                        }
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>@item.newName</h3>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("News", "News", new { id = item.newId })" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:white ;color:black ">Read More</a>
                            @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</button>*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add `class="active"` to the first element in the list you can either:

```
@{int v = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item@(v == 0 ? " active" : "")">
            @item.newName
        </div>
    </div>
    v++;
}
```

Or:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
{
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item@(item.i == 0 ? " active" : "")">
            @item.value.newName
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you @RickL, part of problem is solved, now the news not under each other but the left and right controls still not working, do you know why?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4? The html is different for bootstrap v4 [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp)